# Using toJSONPretty();

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to work with JSON objects with DynamoDB and am having difficulty.
I'm trying to follow the tutorial:
http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-json-and-more/

I wanted to use `toJSONPretty();` on my object but the method is not recognized. I don't think I have the right gradle dependencies. I"m currently using:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.0'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.0'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.0'
```

Previously, my dynamo client was set up using the imports:

```
 import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
 import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
```

But looking at code from Dynamo/JSON tutorials, I see the import:

```
 import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
```

This seems to be required if you want to use the type DynamoDB as it:

```
 DynamoDB dynamo = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(...));
```

I don't understand the difference between these libraries or how they relate to each other. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/DynamoDB.html) class is a higher-level abstraction of the AmazonDynamoDB API. It you [create](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/DynamoDB.html#DynamoDB%28com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB%29) it with an instance of the AmazonDynamoDB inteface or a Regions object. AmazonDynamoDBClient implements the AmazonDynamoDB interface. Even if you pass a Regions object, an instance of a class that implements AmazonDynamoDB is created behind the scenes. Then, you [get a Table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/DynamoDB.html#getTable%28java.lang.String%29) so that you can perform data-plane operations like [GetItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table.html#getItem%28com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.spec.GetItemSpec%29) and [PutItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table.html#putItem%28com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item%29). The [Item](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Item.html) class is one that has a [toJSONPretty](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Item.html#toJSONPretty%28%29) method. To sum up, the DynamoDB class uses an implementation of the AmazonDynamoDB interface behind the scenes to provide you with Items that you can call toJSONPretty() on.

Comment: Thank you. I did, however, have to adjust my gradle depedencies. I think using:
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.0'
is insufficient.I replaced this with:
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.9.33'
but it takes forever to build. Where can I find out how to optimize my dependencies?

Comment: Instead of pulling in the entire SDK, you could pull in just the parts needed for DynamoDB, by "compile com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:1.9.33". The name of your dependencies may depend on the platform you are developing for.

Comment: I can't seem to get the right combination of dependencies here. I either have conflicts or I get red because a library is not being covered. For example, you suggestions left out the cognito imports. Here's all the dependencies I'm playing with, in various combinations:
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.9.33'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.9.33'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:1.9.33'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.0'

Comment: Previous to this JSON exercise, I was just using core, ddb, and dbmapper